# REDCapR redcap_read() function missing observations when querying all records in the database

Tags: r, redcap

I've got a REDCap database of >5000 records where I would like to return just a few variables from each record using the REDCap API and the `REDCapR` package in R. Normally, this can be accomplished very easily with `redcap_read()`, but the function has been returning the error:
`

```
── Column specification ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
cols(
  record_id = col_double(),
  redcap_repeat_instrument = col_logical(),
  redcap_repeat_instance = col_logical(),
  first_name = col_character(),
  last_name = col_character(),
  `NA` = col_logical()
)

Error in redcap_read(redcap_uri = retrieve_credential_local(my_file_path,  : 
  There are 100 subject(s) that are missing rows in the returned dataset. REDCap's PHP code is likely trying to process too much text in one bite.

Common solutions this problem are:
  - specifying only the records you need (w/ `records`)
  - specifying only the fields you need (w/ `fields`)
  - specifying only the forms you need (w/ `forms`)
  - specifying a subset w/ `filter_logic`
  - reduce `batch_size
```

By default, the batch size is set to 100, so the console displays missing subject records equal to whatever the `batch_size` parameter is set to.

The following code has worked before for much smaller REDCap projects (~200-300 records):

```
library(REDCapR)

df <- redcap_read(
  redcap_uri = my_redcap_uri,
  token = my_token,
  fields = c(
    "record_id",
    "first_name",
    "last_name"),
  raw_or_label_headers = 'raw',
  verbose = TRUE
)$data
```

I've set the parameter `verbose=TRUE` in this example because during troubleshooting, I wanted to see if I could identify what was going wrong, but each individual batch returned an HTTP status code of 200. From what I understood of the documentation and source code of the `redcap_read()` function, after looping through each batch, they're all stacked together using `dplyr::bind_rows()`. Then, R checks to see whether any rows are missing, and if so, prints out the error message above.

The strange part is that when executing the same request inside of REDCap's API Playground, there are no missing rows. All record IDs, first names, and last names are returned as requested. Additionally, requesting *only* `record_id` is successful. I'm also not sure where the column `NA` of type `logical` is appearing from whenever I try to include `first_name` and `last_name`, as it's not part of the variables requested in the `fields` parameter and does not appear whenever only `record_id` is requested.

```
df <- redcap_read(
  redcap_uri = my_redcap_uri,
  token = my_token,
  fields = c("record_id"),
  raw_or_label_headers = 'raw',
  verbose = TRUE
)$data

head(df)

############
── Column specification ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
cols(
  record_id = col_double(),
  redcap_repeat_instrument = col_logical(),
  redcap_repeat_instance = col_logical()
)

record_id redcap_repeat_instrument redcap_repeat_instance
1           NA                      NA                     
2           NA                      NA                     
3           NA                      NA                     
4           NA                      NA                     
5           NA                      NA                     
6           NA                      NA                     
7           NA                      NA                     
8           NA                      NA                     
9           NA                      NA                     
10          NA                      NA
```

If I'm missing something obvious, please let me know!

Comment: I figured out what was going on--the R code was fine, it was one record in my REDCap database which had a non-ASCII character in their name that was not properly encoded  (`é`, or `&eacute;`) so it appeared as a black diamond with a question mark inside. REDCapR did not know what to do with this and threw an error, but once I found the problem record in the API Playground and properly encoded it in UTF-8, the error was resolved and the code ran smoothly.